# Mongoose not honoring schema and inserting wrong data types

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a strange problem with Mongoose not honoring the schema I've defined. I am passing data that properly conforms to the specified schema, however I'm either encountering cast errors, or the data (when I exclude the information that fails to cast) is ending up in mongo  as the wrong datatypes.

The schema is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: Number, unique: true, dropDups: true },
    referralCode: String,
    dateStarted: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    accountType: Number,
    accountCategories: [String],
    beneficiaries: [{
        id: Number,
        relationshipType: Number,
        percentage: Number,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        middleInitial: String,
        mailingAddress: {
            address1: String,
            address2: String,
            address3: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            country: String,
            postalCode: String
        },
        ssn: String,
        birthDate: Date,
        isPrimary: Boolean
    }],
    accountOwner: {
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        middleInitial: String,
        birthDate: Date,
        ssn: String,
        phoneNumber: String,
        mailingAddress: {
            address1: String,
            address2: String,
            address3: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            country: String,
            postalCode: String
        },
        physicalAddress: {
            address1: String,
            address2: String,
            address3: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            country: String,
            postalCode: String
        }
    },
    fundsTransfer: {
        bankName: String,
        type: Number,
        transferType: Number,
        routingNumber: String,
        accountNumber: String,
        currentYearAmount: Number,
        previousYearAmount: Number
    },
    accountTransfer: {
        accountType: Number,
        custodianName: String,
        accountNumber: String,
        phoneNumber: String,
        faxNumber: String,
        cashAmount: Number,
        cashPortionOptions: Number,
        expediteOption: Boolean,
        otherAccountType: String,
        planType: Number
    },
    wizardFlags: {
        doCashContrib: Boolean,
        doCashTransfer: Boolean,
        doCashContribAndTransfer: Boolean,
        doAssetTransfer: Boolean
    }
});

var Account = mongoose.model("Account", AccountSchema);

module.exports = Account;
```

The data being passed in is as follows:

```
this.mockAccountState = {
    userId: 9,
    referralCode: "",
    dateStarted: Date.now(),
    accountOwner: {
        firstName: "Test",
        lastName: "User",
        middleInitial: "X",
        birthDate: null,
        ssn: "123-45-6789",
        phoneNumber: "(123) 456-7890",
        mailingAddress: {
            address1: "123 A Street",
            address2: "",
            address3: "",
            city: "A City",
            state: "CO",
            country: "US",
            postalCode: "12345"
        },
        physicalAddress: null
    },
    accountType: 0,
    accountCategories: [],
    fundsTransfer: {
        bankName: "",
        type: 0,
        transferType: 1,
        routingNumber: "123456789",
        accountNumber: "111222333444",
        currentYearAmount: 6000,
        previousYearAmount: 0
    },
    assetTransfer: {},
    hasBeneficiaries: false,
    beneficiaries: [],
    wizardFlags: {
        doCashContrib: true,
        doCashTransfer: false,
        doCashContribAndTransfer: false,
        doAssetTransfer: false
    }
};
```

If I pass in a non-empty string value for bankName, I get the following error:

> Error updating account: CastError: Cast to number failed for value
>   "Bank of Test" at path "fundsTransfer"

If I exclude bankName, then the data that actually ends up in the database is as follows:

[image]

If I select this data using the mongo shell, I get:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("536ae87342d6347028b42e1e"),
    "userId" : 1, 
    "referralCode" : "", 
    "accountType" : 1, 
    "wizardFlags" : { 
        "doAssetTransfer" : false, 
        "doCashContribAndTransfer" : false, 
        "doCashTransfer" : false, 
        "doCashContrib" : true
    }, 
    "accountOwner" : { 
        "mailingAddress" : { 
            "postalCode" : "12345", 
            "country" : "US",
            "state" : "CO",
            "city" : "A City", 
            "address3" : "", 
            "address2" : "", 
            "address1" : "123 A Street" 
        }, 
        "physicalAddress" : {  }, 
        "phoneNumber" : "(123) 456-7890",
        "ssn" : "123-45-6789",
        "birthDate" : null,
        "middleInitial" : "X",
        "lastName" : "User",
        "firstName" : "Test"
    }, 
    "beneficiaries" : [ ], 
    "accountCategories" : [ "3" ],
    "dateStarted" : ISODate("2014-05-08T02:14:05.379Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "accountTransfer" : {  }, 
    "fundsTransfer" : { 
        "bankName" : null,
        "type" : 0, 
        "transferType" : 1, 
        "routingNumber" : 123456789, 
        "accountNumber" : 111222333444,
        "currentYearAmount" : 6000, 
        "previousYearAmount" : 0 
    }
}
```

However the data that Mongoose actually returns is:

```
{
    "dateStarted":"2014-05-08T02:14:05.379Z",
    "accountCategories":["3"],
    "beneficiaries":[],
    "accountOwner":{
        "mailingAddress":{
            "address1":"123 A Street",
            "address2":"",
            "address3":"",
            "city":"A City",
            "state":"CO",
            "country":"US",
            "postalCode":"12345"
        },
        "physicalAddress":{},
        "firstName":"Test",
        "lastName":"User",
        "middleInitial":"X",
        "birthDate":null,
        "ssn":"123-45-6789",
        "phoneNumber":"(123) 456-7890"
    },
    "accountTransfer":{},
    "wizardFlags":{
       "doCashContrib":true,
       "doCashTransfer":false,
       "doCashContribAndTransfer":false,
       "doAssetTransfer":false
   },
   "__v":0,
   "accountType":1,
   "referralCode":"",
   "userId":1,
   "_id":"536ae87342d6347028b42e1e"
}
```

The fundsTransfer child object isn't even present, even though it is definitely in mongodb.

I'm quite confused. I don't understand why the rest of the schema works, but the fundsTransfer object simply refuses to work. The data and the schema match, something somewhere, I am quit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `AccountSchema`, you need to change the `type` field definition from:

```
type: Number,
```

to

```
type: {type: Number},
```

Otherwise, Mongoose thinks you're defining the type of the parent `fundsTransfer` object as a `Number` instead of defining a field named 'type' within it.

Comment: Thanks, Johnny. I actually ended up figuring this out early this morning. Just one of those "DOH!!!" moments, when it finally hit me why the "path" was "fundsTranfer" and not "bankName". Hopefully this will get some upvotes, in case anyone else encounters a similar problem, because it is one of those things that isn't obvious until you experience it.